# Decomposing a binary function into regions (regions that are not zero measures) with constant value

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$. 
What assumption do we have to make, in order to be able to decompose the domain of any $f$ into regions $R_1, R_2, R_3, ....$, such that:

- The regions are mutually disjoint
- The regions cover the whole input space
- The function is constant in each region: $f(x) = f(y), \forall x, y \in R_i$
- Regions that are not zero measures.

**Question:** What conditions are required to have for $f$, in order to be able to get such decomposition for any such $f$?

---

Some ideas:

Initially, I was thinking that Reimann integrability should be enough. Now  I'm thinking it might not enough; e.g., consider $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in \{1/1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, ...\}$, and $f(x) = 1$ otherwise.  It is Riemann integrable.

Comment: What do you call the size of a region?

Comment: What about $f^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}(1)$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net updated it to "measure". Better?

Comment: What do you mean by "region"?

Comment: @mfl are you saying that if a binary function is **invertible**, I can always dempose it into two sets (one corrsponding to output 1 and one corresponding to output 0)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean when say "invertible". But if you have a function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ then you have two regions $f^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}(1)$. Obviously they satisfy the first three conditions. The fourth depends on the function.

Comment: @mlf ah you're right, that's what I want. Any thoughts what can I assume to have the fourth condition as well?

Comment: You need at least for $f$ to be measurable.

Comment: yeah measurability and that the inverse image of either 0 or 1 has positive but finite measure. Integrability is not enough, $f(x)=0, \forall x$ except one point is integrable.